# Nginx External Ip not accessible Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have an Nginx ingress controller that I created with helm using this cmd

```
helm upgrade --install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace dev \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.digest="" \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux
```

running this cmd kdev get svc -o wide (kdev is kubectl with dev ns)

I get

> nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer
> 10.0.106.37    20.84.232.100   80:32048/TCP,443:30725/TCP   4m7s   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=nginx-ingress,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx

and this is my service ingress file

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/v1$uri
    
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /wallet
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: wallet-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

and running curl http://20.84.232.100/wallet just waits then returns timeout error

curl: (28) Failed to connect to 20.84.232.100 port 80 after 75005 ms: Operation timed out

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here because kdev get ingress -o wide gives me

```
dev-ingress   nginx   *       20.84.232.100   80
```

Any help on resolving this is appreciated.

I am using Azure AKS
Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl get endpoints`?

Comment: kubernetes   52.141.114.342:443

Comment: can you share the output of `kubectl get svc -o wide` ?

Comment: Are you sure your rewrite rules are correct? I am not familiar with this notation `/api/v1$uri`

Comment: @divine I shared that output  already, it is part of the question.

Comment: @FritzDuchardt Yeah, I believe so. The expected url is `http://ip/api/v1/wallet`

Answer (score 2):

What's your AKS version ? Can you also post your chart version `helm list --namespace dev`. There's chance if you have AKS version > 1.22 and the last version of nginx that you need to configure your externalTrafficPolicy :

```
--set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local
```

More details : https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2903

PS : You should always deploy helm chart by specifiying the --version to be sure to get the version you want (and not the random last one at the time you run the command).